# Google OAuth restricted scope verification denied for wrong reason

Tags: google-oauth

We have an application that currently supports users integrating their Google accounts to allow us to index their Gmail, Google Drive and Google Calendar content. We use the Google OAuth process to ask for these permissions, and had gone through Google's verification process in the past to support this.

Recently, Google rolled out a new OAuth verification process for restricted scopes (which now include reading gmail and calendar). We've been engaged in completing the new process for weeks now, and they've been very slow to respond, and have even temporarily blocked us from authorizing new users. Our latest communication with them had them claiming that we were a "development" app and that we should submit for verification when we are in production. I responded to them saying that we are a production application, just have an invite-only process to let new users in, but have 1000s of users and are expecting to grow very quickly in the new few months. Given the amount of frustration their support has already caused me, I'd really like to get in touch with a real person there. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get in touch them?

If anyone from Google is on this forum, I'd also love to get some help. This is holding up us letting in new users into our product.

Have already responded to the thread saying that we're a production app. Have also forwarded the thread to oauth-feedback@google.com.

Comment: This situation is only going to get tougher for you starting July 15, if you are accessing a user's data. https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/06/gmails-api-lockdown-will-kill-some-third-party-app-access-starting-july-15/

Comment: Once you read that article, your best bet will be to create a finalized program source code package, and have your application audited, which is not free. If you have not applied to be a Google partner, get that application submitted.

Comment: We have submitted the application, and that's the process I'm trying to get help with right now.

Comment: I suggested "Partner application", not OAuth application. Take the time to read the article that I linked. You will have a better understanding that Google is locking down user data access and that your application "as is" will not be approved.

Comment: Ahh thanks @JohnHanley, assuming you're talking about this partner program: https://cloud.google.com/partners/become-a-partner/build-engagement-model/

Comment: No, that page is when you are already a partner. Start at the beginning: https://cloud.google.com/partners/become-a-partner/